# What is the Java equivalent of c# Queue

Tags: java, asynchronous, queue

In a c# code, which must be ported to java, there is a section like this:

```
this._RequestQueue.Enqueue(aVariableAsAnOnwTable);
```

I googled, that DelayedQueue is the useful equivalent of c#'s Queue object.

a) is that right ?

b1)if (a) -> why does this fail in java when i use

```
this._RequestQueue.add(aVariableAsAnOnwTable);
```

b2) if(!a) -> how else can I achieve this to have nearly the same behaviour in my java application?

THX in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with [`Queue<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ^this. It even has 13 different implementations!

Comment: "I googled, that DelayedQueue is the useful equivalent of c#'s Queue object." Where did you read that? Seems very odd to me...

Comment: Type of queue in c# is simply System.Collections.Queue.

Comment: what do you mean by: it fails

Comment: @icbytes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html using add for enqueue and remove for dequeue might be the closest

Comment: @ John: Sorry, I did not read it, i just assumed, that DelayedQueue seemed to be the most fitting after some research in the web. @Philipp: It fails with the debug message to cannot cast the table to java.util.concurrent

Comment: @icbytes can you post the exception/error and more code of how you defined the queue?

Comment: @Cruncher So? Choose which fits your need.

Comment: @gyabraham I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to. I was saying that the 13 implementations is a good thing.

Comment: Could anyone provide a helpful snippet regarding the usage ?
As it seems like, my Table class must implement Delayed. Is this right ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

So some more basic information about this 
My table-class is basically a class, which extends the ArrayList class. class MyTable extends ArrayList ... where MyStructure is a String. I now resolved my error and made my class implementing Delayed.

Now I can easily add the Table to the DelayedQueue.

How ever : I get the debug info from choreographer : Skipped 667 frames The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Why COULD this be, or, where should I start troubleshooting?